# ConvertTo-Json does not work with an Exchange Mailboxes "DatabaseSize"

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, exchange-server, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to export the properties of an Exchange 2010 MailboxDatabase on a Windows 2008R2 server (with Powershell 3.0). I do the following:

```
$dbs = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status
ConvertTo-Json $dbs[0].DatabaseSize
```

The resulting JSON is just `{}` - an empty Object. But the output of `$dbs[0].DatabaseSize` is  `320.1 GB (343,742,152,704 bytes)`. Which seems correct but also odd, because it has no clear datatype.

If I export the whole object, the `DatabaseSize` is also empty, despite numerous other properties exported correctly.

How do I export the `DatabaseSize` in valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: `$dbs[0].DatabaseSize` is of type `System.ValueType`. I need to convert it explicitly like so:

```
$dbs[0].DatabaseSize.ToBytes()
```

which gives me a big number which I can perfectly `ConvertTo-Json` :).